# Microsoft Teams: How to automatically add a bot to all incoming calls for users?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

We'd like to add a bot automatically and immediately to all incoming calls for specific users.

Background: The bot provides services depending on the call context like looking up additional information (that depend on the caller), or managing the call.

Is this possible? Currently the users have to add the bot *manually* and *after* taking the call which takes time and might lead to awkward delays.

Comment: Could you please share the sample or document which you are referring for this?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I'm not referring to any specific sample but so far I evaluated the capabilities documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta many of which are implemented in this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp - but adding a bot immediately to an incoming call unfortunetely is not covered anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We cannot add a bot automatically to incoming calls.**

Bot can be added in teams,channels,groupchat,tabs and in messaging extensions.

You can add bot proactively also. But not for incoming calls.

Ref Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-overview#what-you-need-to-know-bots

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Bummer, but thanks for clarifying this. Is this something that might be possible in the future (on the roadmap, or internal discussions at Microsoft)? Or are there technical limitations that render this not feasible at all?

Comment: You can raise an user voice here:

 https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new